# Cannot open database "pubs" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'ESLAM\Eslam_Nora'

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, windows

Hello iam trying to store sum information inside a SQL Server table , but when i run the form and turned to store the data the above runtime error appears also the the pubs database icon in SQL Server is missing the (+) sign how come ! , i wrote that code for inserting  , Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class Add_Client : Form
{

    SqlConnection clientConnection;
    string connString;
    SqlCommand insertCommand; 

   public Add_Client()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connString = "Data Source=.\\INSTANCE2;Initial Catalog=pubs; Integrated security=true ";
        clientConnection = new SqlConnection();
        clientConnection.ConnectionString = connString;
    }

    private void button1_ADD(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
        {

            SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand();
            insertCommand.Connection = clientConnection;
            insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Client_Data values(@Client_Name,@Autorization_No,@Issue_Type,@Status)";
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Client_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 60).Value = txt_Name.Text;
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Autorization_No", SqlDbType.Int, 60).Value = txt_Auth.Text.ToString();
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Issue_Type", SqlDbType.Text, 200).Value = txt_Iss.Text;
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Text, 200).Value = txt_Iss.Text;
            //insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Date To Memorize", SqlDbType.Date, 15).Value=Ca_Mem.se;
            insertCommand.Connection.Open();
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }
        finally
        {
            if (clientConnection != null)
            {
                clientConnection.Close();
            }

        }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use integrated security to access the database. Therefore your windows user needs to be authorized to access the database. Check the security settings for the server and the database.

Comment: how can i check the settings, the database icon in SQL Server missing the + sign !!

Comment: If you're administrating the server, use SQL Server Management Studio and log in using an authorized account (usually sa account). If you're not the administrator, you have to contact your server administrator and ask her for help.

Comment: ok , how can i log in using an authorized account(sa account)?

Comment: `sa` is the system administrator account. While installing SQL Server you're asked to enter a password for that account, so I hope you have it at hand. Then use SSMS as normal and use SQL server authentification entering sa as user and your password.